# How to get SASS working with RequestReduce?

Tags: css, sass, minify, requestreduce

I have a new site that we have started working on that needs to have working SASS combining/minification.

Currently we are using RequestReduce on most of our projects so I have knowledge of the product.

I have installed RequestReduce and its less/sass/coffeescript add-on via the nuget feed. Requestreduce dashboard works fine and handle any css or less file that I add. So less/css/javascript works fine.

When I try to add a scss file the dashboard says it gets a 404. If I request the file manually via browser i get:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

So the file path is correct but there is no handler to take care of the scss file. The nuget added a handler for the less files in web.config but nothing for scss. Adding the mime type in IIS got rid of the error but that only adds the scss as plaintext to the document so that was not a solution. No compiling of the file is done by RequestReduce when i that case.

Anyone know how to get RequestReduce to get hold of the sass file and compile/minify it? Any help appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reflecting of RequestReduce dll:s I found a Sasshandler . So adding that handler to web.config solved the issue. I don't know why the nuget package does not add this with install  but hopefully it will later.

Here is the code to add to web.cofig to get sass working with requestreduce:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="requestreducesass" path="*.scss" verb="GET" type="RequestReduce.SassLessCoffee.SassHandler,RequestReduce.SassLessCoffee" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
    <handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this helps others with the same issue!